# Looping through a CSV with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to loop through a CSV file using Powershell but for some reason my `foreach` loop will not execute.  I looked online but couldn't find anything about why this would be.  Strangely if I use a simple for loop I can iterate, however I'm just wondering what the issue is for future reference.

My code is below:

```
Clear-Host

$path = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
$csv = Import-Csv $path\Book1.csv -Delimiter ";"

Write-Host $csv
Write-Host @($csv).Length

#When debugging the foreach doesnt get executed
ForEach($l in $csv){
    Write-Host $l.ProjectManager
}

#This works fine
for($i = 0; $i -lt @($csv).Length; $i++){
    Write-Host $csv.Item($i).ProjectManager 
}
```

Here's the CSV file:

```
ProjectName;ProjectOwner;ProjectManager;ProjectNumber
Test1;Rich Banks;Monica Ruden;1234567891
Test2;Steve Jones;Steve Gibb;1234567892
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Both loops work for me. Is this the actual code that you are running?

Comment: Can you post a sample of what your csv content is like? Also, I would try replacing the semi-colons with commas. Theoretically, any delimiter should work, but when troubleshooting strange problems like this, it's best to go back to the "basics".

Comment: do you have a "ProjectManager" column in your csv ?

Comment: @EBGreen this is the actual code

Comment: @McKenning ive tried with commas.  Same issue

Comment: @toshi Yes there is a ProjectManager column.  It doesnt even get to the contents of teh foreach loop.  The dubugger just skips it after the foreach declaration line

Comment: could you get your file as follow : $PSScriptRoot\Book1.csv

Comment: I'would use comment not "//"   but "#"

Comment: @toshi the comments are just what i put in the post on here not in the script.  Ill change that in the post to avoid confusion.  I tried $PSScriptRoot but that didnt make a difference, although i didnt know that variable existed so ive learnt something today :-)

Comment: your code is working as expected on my computer.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and your CSV to two files and ran them on a freshly deployed 2012 R2 VM. Here is the output (which is exactly what I'd expect): `@{ProjectName=Test1; ProjectOwner=Rich Banks; ProjectManager=Monica Ruden; ProjectNumber=1234567891} @{ProjectName=Test2
; ProjectOwner=Steve Jones; ProjectManager=Steve Gibb; ProjectNumber=1234567892}
2
Monica Ruden
Steve Gibb
Monica Ruden
Steve Gibb`

Comment: Oooh..Oooh!! - From this: ***"The dubugger just skips it after the foreach declaration line"*** Am I to take it that you are running this in the ISE? If so, I suspect that this is the issue. Try running it in a regular prompt rather than the ISE.

Comment: Along the same lines as @EBGreen, if this is in the ISE have you tried simply closing the ISE and then opening it and starting fresh to make sure you don't have something in the session messing with you? That fixes a surprising number of issues people have when working in the ISE.

Comment: @EBGreen.  YOu are correct.  The debugger was skipping the foreach.  If you put that up as an answer ill make it as so.  Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: It wouldn't be fair if I got rep everytime the ISE did something stupid. I stopped using it long ago. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems ISE was skipping the for loop

Answer (score -1):

to recover the lines in an array i would use 
get-content

then your loop will work.

$arrayWithAllLines = get-content $PSScriptRoot\Book1.csv

Comment: This answer is very contrary to the spirit of powershell. Treating CSV rows as strings is far less flexible than treating them as objects.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with this code. It runs as expected on Windows 2012 R2 (PowerShell v3.0).

Output is as follows:

```
@{ProjectName=Test1; ProjectOwner=Rich Banks; ProjectManager=Monica Ruden; ProjectNumber=1234567891} @{ProjectName=Test2
; ProjectOwner=Steve Jones; ProjectManager=Steve Gibb; ProjectNumber=1234567892}
2
Monica Ruden
Steve Gibb
Monica Ruden
Steve Gibb
```

I would look at environmental factors. What OS / PS version are you using? Have you tried it on other platforms?

Comment: This is also not an answer.